# Sort in LINQ based on certain order

Tags: linq

I have the following records:

```
ID  Type  TypeID

1   BHD    2
2   BHD    2
3   AUY    4
4   CDL    5
5   BUL    6
6   ZUL    7
```

What I like to do is to sort it so it is sorted by following where AUY, BHD and CDL are sorted alphatically and BUL and ZUL are appended at the end.

```
    AUY
    BHD
    CDL
    BUL
    ZUL
```

How can this be done in Linq. Note that I have TypeID that I am sorting by.

I have a foreach as such:

foreach (var types in ent.OrderBy(s => s.TypeID)

Answer (score 0):

You can always sort in multiple steps:

```
foreach(var types in ent
    .OrderBy(s => s.Type == "BUL" || s.Type == "ZUL" ? 1 : 0)
    .ThenBy(s => s.Type))
{
    // Do your thing here...
}
```